# Block access to old git repos after migration

Tags: git, hook

We had a bunch of local git repos on our server and recently we have moved all of those to a new place (same code, different remotes). We don't want to delete the old ones, but some of our developers might still point to those. What's a good way to block access to those repos - or even better, show a message, mentioning the new remotes for ones who try to push stuff to it-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at git server side hooks, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

For an example, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

To totally block things, just create a simple "update" hook that emits "deprecated repo/read only - use < url > instead to push" or something like that to stdout and then exit with a 1, and the update will be rejected and the user will see your string when they try to push.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks David.

Comment: No prob. Thanks for the uv.